# Losing hard drive space on my Mac and not sure why

Tags: hard-drive, mac, disk-space

I'm running MacOS Big Sur, Version 11.6 on a late 2020 MacBook Pro. I have a 1 Tb hard drive that had about 180 Gb free a few months ago, but I am progressively losing space. Now I have about 90 Gb free and decreasing weekly. I have downloaded some documents and applications that take up a few Gigs, but nothing that should have taken up so much space. What is going on?

Comment: You could use `du` to identify the files which take up space. No one knows what goes on on YOUR hard drive...

Comment: That's why I'm asking for tips about how to troubleshoot this. There seems to be a lot more space that's taken up than is accounted for by an inventory of the files.

Comment: Well, you are obviously looking for a "disk space analyzer" then. I am not familiar with MacOS, but `du` should work on every *nix system. There are for sure GUI alternatives.

Comment: Are you 100% the space is lost? Do you use Time Machine at all? Because Time Machine does this: It of course backs up to an external hard drive. But when that drive is not connected or found, Time Machine stores local snapshots of data. So you could, for example, not connect to the Time Machine disk for weeks and the local drive will fill up with snapshots. And the second the machine connects to the Time Machine drive, it will copy those snapshots over and the prune the local MacBook snapshots.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 Thanks, I haven't used Time Machine in a while, so that might be it. How would I find where those snapshots are?

Comment: @user2561523 Look at this Apple [support doc on how to do it](https://support.apple.com/guide/disk-utility/view-apfs-snapshots-dskuf82354dc/mac).